# How do I create a Custom FB share button in adobe muse?

Tags: facebook, adobe, muse

I am completely new to this field and stackoverflow, so bear with me.

I have created a site in muse (designed not coded, of course),

This is my problem... just stuck in creating a "Fb share button"

But I got an idea

Step 1, when user clicks a button, loads up a lightbox with fb login or share menu

Step 2, when user enter necessary information it is posted on their wall

Step 3, redirect them to another page.

Please help me...

Comment: To make this work your gonna have to download the facebook api. You will need to connect to facebook as with a developer account. After you connect you can gain permission from users to post on their behalf or gain information from their profiles.

Comment: can you elaborate these steps in answer, so that i can accept...

Comment: How about I describe how to setup an app and build a login with php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muse already has in-built features for this kinds, just look into social behind widgets.

Instead of setting up your pages using php this is much more easier.

Also Go to Facebook SDK docs and read more about how to redirect your links.

Its more easier if you follow those  instructions instead of creating everything using php, which is much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to create a new facebook application [Setup App Here](https://developers.facebook.com/)

Then you will need to download the facebook `PHP SDK` [Here](https://codeload.github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/zip/4.0-dev)

At this point you will need to unzip the SDK to your root dir of wherever your hosting your website.

If you are working on a local host you will need to install `xampp wamp lamp or mamp` in order to properly setup a server on your localhost for testing you `php` This is because `php` is a service scripting language. If you are not familiar with php please follow this tutorial to get php up and running before you can finish this tutorial.  [PHP Setup Here](https://blog.udemy.com/xampp-tutorial/)

If you prefere a video tutorial, there are plenty on youtube.com

Once you have the `facebook sdk and php` running on your server or localhost you will need to connect to facebook,

Create inside your new directory a new PHP file and add the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'facebook-php-sdk/autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

$api_key = 'FACEBOOK_APP_ID';
$api_secret = 'FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET';
$redirect_login_url = 'http://www.yoursite.com/somefolder/file.php';
```

To post a link to a user’s Facebook timeline, the application need an authorization. This is actually a complex function, add this code below the others in your PHP file.

```
/ initialize your app using your key and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($api_key, $api_secret);

// create a helper opject which is needed to create a login URL
// the $redirect_login_url is the page a visitor will come to after login
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( $redirect_login_url);

// First check if this is an existing PHP session
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
    // create new session from the existing PHP sesson
    $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );
    try {
        // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
        if ( !$session->validate() ) $session = null;
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        // catch any exceptions and set the sesson null
        $session = null;
        echo 'No session: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}  elseif ( empty( $session ) ) {
    // the session is empty, we create a new one
    try {
        // the visitor is redirected from the login, let's pickup the session
        $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    } catch( FacebookRequestException $e ) {
        // Facebook has returned an error
        echo 'Facebook (session) request error: '.$e->getMessage();
    } catch( Exception $e ) {
        // Any other error
        echo 'Other (session) request error: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Now I create a GraphObject from the response and the script outputs the data to the browser. I use the Facebook message ID for a second request:

```
if ( isset ( $msgid ) ) {
        // we only need to the sec. part of this ID
        $parts = explode('_', $msgid);
        try {
            $request2 = new FacebookRequest(
                $session,
                'GET',
                '/'.$parts[1]
            );
            $response2 = $request2->execute();
            $graphObject2 = $response2->getGraphObject();
            // the GET response object
            echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject2, 1 ) . '</pre>';
        } catch ( FacebookRequestException $e ) {
            // show any error for this facebook request
            echo 'Facebook (get) request error: '.$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Last but not least we take a look on the code which creates the login URL (place this code below the other).

```
} else {
    // we need to create a new session, provide a login link
    echo 'No session, please <a href="'. $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'publish_actions' ) ).'">login</a>.';
}
```

Following this tutorial will connect a user to facebook to login then allow you to post a link to a facebook user's timeline. This is not a simple task and will take trial and error, especially if your new to this type of thing.

The full tutorial I based this off of can be found here,

[Full Tutorial Here](http://www.finalwebsites.com/facebook-api-php-tutorial/)

Comment: _“This is not a simple task”_ – no, not if you are going the complicated, server-side way. Using the Share button, Share dialog or Feed dialog on the client side would be much easier (assuming muse allows to include some HTML/JavaScript code directly.)

Comment: He says this, Step 1, when user clicks a button, loads up a lightbox with fb login or share menu

Step 2, when user enter necessary information it is posted on their wall

Step 3, redirect them to another page. How do you purpose doing that without php or super extensive javascript? You cannot post to a facebook users wall without having a developer app and the correct authorization or user permissions.

Comment: Using the dialogs doesn’t need any permissions. (“He says this” – yes, but basically all he/she wants, is a share button. Those steps outlined probably just mean he/she doesn’t know there is an easier way to do this.)

Comment: True. lol I hate the facebook SDK man. It is super confusing. I was writing that thinking there is no way he / she will ever make it through this. But after struggling with facebook api so much I feel obligated to try to help anyone who is confused. It looks like you probably have better information than I do, by the look at your profile.

Comment: thanks  NichoDiaz  for helping me out, this way it's bit complicated, but i got the results... btw i went and researched on developer.facebook and find it much easier... anyway thanks for helping me out...